# Animation in beamer: nested lists

Tags: beamer

Beamer has the `[<+->]` option for lists which makes each item appears separately.
However, it also make items in nested lists appear separately too.
How do I make each nested list appear as a whole?

E.g.,

```
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item A 
  \begin{itemize}
    \item A1
    \item A2
  \end{itemize}
\item B
  \begin{itemize}
    \item B1
    \item B2
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

each item appears separately (IOW, 6 slides are created).
I want all As to appear simultaneously and all B appear simultaneously
(IOW, two slides in PDF).

PS. I would rather avoid the explicit `<i->` annotation.

Comment: Does the PS mean that you would rather avoid adding `[<1->]` to the two inner `\begin{itemize}`?

Comment: yes, exactly!..

Comment: Or you can just \pause

Comment: @Mark: yes, but I want to issue a _single_ command to handle the situation, not one command per item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe you can. In the documentation ([Beamer User Guide, v.3.33](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), section 12.1 on p.110) it says "The *⟨default overlay specification⟩* is inherited by subenvironments. Naturally, in a subenvironment you can reset it locally by setting it to `<1->`."  I may be wrong and there may be a hack around it, but it seems that this was the intended behaviour.

I suggest that you define your own `innerItemize` environment:

```
\newenvironment{innerItemize}{%
  \begin{itemize}[<1->]%
}{%
  \end{itemize}%
}

\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item A 
  \begin{innerItemize}
    \item A1
    \item A2
  \end{innerItemize}
\item B
  \begin{innerItemize}
    \item B1
    \item B2
  \end{innerItemize}
\end{itemize}
```

---

If you insist on your original code, you could hack the `itemize` environment to use the default one for the outer level and turn to the equivalent of `innerItemize` for inner levels.  I don't think I'd like such a hack but this is how you'd go:

```
\let\oldItemize\itemize
\let\endoldItemize\enditemize
\newcommand{\myItemize}[1][<1->]{\oldItemize[#1]}
\def\endmyItemize{\endoldItemize}
\let\itemize\myItemize
\let\enditemize\endmyItemize
```